# Store data temporary in sql server and MVC

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, model-view-controller

Suppose i have developed a tool which is used by multiple users,also have features that allows one user to configure tool in multiple ways through different versions.in current scenario all data are saved in database directly and it working fine.
But now user opened one version called version_1 and change its data and now user don't want to permanently save that changes so we need to have option to undo changes from database made by them than we need to rollback changes to unchanged state.

we have options like copy of the existing tables and perform operation on them second is to create json of all existing data.

any best way to do that.

Comment: use sessions for this.. they were build for these kind of situations. a session is maintained for each user.. and when its final.. save it to database

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Event Sourcing.

Capture all changes to an application state as a sequence of events, makes it possible to reverse events.

http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html